# How do I remove the global flag from a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a user (developer) provided regular expression, I need to remove the global flag if it exists, on Firefox 38 and above [you can just set it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global):

```
the_regex.global = false;
```

However that is not supported elsewhere.  So, I have created this pair of functions:

```
function deGlobal(regex) {
  if (!regex instanceof RegExp) return regex;
  if (!regex.global) return regex;
  var parts = regExpParts(regex);
  console.log(parts);
  if (parts) {
    return new RegExp(parts.pattern, parts.flags.replace("g", ""));
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function regExpParts(regex) {
  if (!regex instanceof RegExp) return false;
  var regex_string = regex.toString();
  var flags = regex_string.substring(regex_string.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  var pattern = regex_string.substring(1, regex_string.lastIndexOf('/'));
  return {
    flags: flags,
    pattern: pattern
  };
}
```

Which for all of my test cases is doing great, but it seems like a very error prone method.

Is there a case where these functions wouldn't work or there a better cross browser method of doing this?

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/324k2as5/.

Comment: ~4 years late but here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56078985/10415695) that explains how to remove and replace regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simplify it to

```js
new RegExp(regex.source, regex.flags);
```

Note [`RegExp.prototype.flags`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/flags) is introduced in ES6, so you may need to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/flags#Polyfill) it:

```js
if (RegExp.prototype.flags === undefined) {
  Object.defineProperty(RegExp.prototype, 'flags', {
    configurable: true,
    get: function() {
      return this.toString().match(/[gimuy]*$/)[0];
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description) constructor to remove/overwrite the flags?

For example, when you log `x` from the following code:

```
let x = /ab(c)/g;
x = new RegExp(x, "");
```

You should get the following output:

```
/ab(c)/
```

You could even overwrite the flags, like this:

```
let x = /ab(c)/g;
x = new RegExp(x, "mi");
```

Which should output:

```
/ab(c)/mi
```

Good luck.

Comment: Seems good to me. You might want to edit the second line to another variable or remove the second `let` on `x` again.