# What happens if you pass a regular expression to the "RegExp" constructor?

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have the following regular expression:

```
/hello\sworld\!/g
```

If I pass this regular expression to the `RegExp` constructor, without quotation marks:

```
new RegExp(/hello\sworld\!/g)
```

Would it return a regular expression containing `/hello\sworld\!/g`, like this:

```
/\/hello\sworld\!\/\g/
```

Or would it return the original regular expression?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's somewhat common for self-answers. Some people go "oh, if you knew the answer, why did you ask then" and downvote. I really dislike this but alas, it happens. For what it's worth, I find this self-answer very good. I've seen others that aren't and deserved a downvoted only because they were either bad or simply irrelevant. I think yours is fine and meaningful. I hope it helps somebody. I'd suggest an improvement - you can expand on what happens if you pass a regex literal *with* a flag to a regex constructor - `new RegExp(/abc/i)` - right now that's not explicitly covered.

Comment: @VLAZ Great suggestion, I've done some testing and updated my answer.

Comment: My only problem now is that I cannot upvote twice. I knew that `new RegExp(/abc/i)` produces `/abc/i` but it never occurred to me that you can pass a flag *and* a regex literal with a flag to the constructor.

Comment: Thank you! Also, I was kinda hoping that it would throw an error when I tired it but it was a real *"aha! gotcha"* moment when I saw that it worked. I tried doing the same in several other languages but most raised errors/exceptions saying that duplicate arguments and/or multiple flag definitions aren't allowed. Except for TypeScript which only gave a linter warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description), the following expressions create the same regular expression:

```
new RegExp("ab+c", "i");
new RegExp(/ab+c/, "i");
```

Expected result:

```
/ab+c/i
```

The result will also be the same if you pass a regex literal with a flag but don't define new flags in the second argument, for example:

```
new RegExp(/ab+c/i)
```

Should return the same regex literal (`/ab+c/i`), but if you do specify new regex flags (in the second argument) all existing flags will be removed.

```
new RegExp(/ab+c/i, "")
new RegExp(/ab+c/i, "g")
new RegExp(/ab+c/i, "m")
```

Expected result:

```
/ab+c/
/ab+c/g
/ab+c/m
```

What does the literal notation do?

> The literal notation provides a compilation of the regular expression when the expression is evaluated.

When should I use the literal notation?

> Use literal notation when the regular expression will remain constant. For example, if you use literal notation to construct a regular expression used in a loop, the regular expression won't be recompiled on each iteration.

What does the constructor function do?

> The constructor of the regular expression object (for example, new `RegExp('ab+c')`) provides runtime compilation of the regular expression.

When should I use the constructor function?

> Use the constructor function when you know the regular expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the pattern and are getting it from another source, such as user input.

Good luck.

Comment: I agree with @VLAZ comment on the question that this is a good self-answered Q/A — you may want to consider adding a _stack snippet_ with output to the snippet's console to _demonstrate_ what you've written.

Comment: So, it turns out I actually found use for this. Great timing, I suppose - I'd like to reward you with a bounty but I need to wait for 24 hours. Cheers :)

Comment: @VLAZ Gee, thanks! Although an up-vote would have been just as appreciated :)